# How could I do a dynamic mat-select so that it is possible to add new elements to the list that feeds it

Tags: javascript, angular

Good morning, how about, I have a query, I have a form that I use in angular to create new equipment, and one of its fields (**Tipo is called the fields**) is a drop-down list with values ​​that come directly from the Json, which consumption, is that is, that drop-down list is the unique values ​​of that column in the database, the question is that when there is a new device with a new "type" property value (that is, in the unique values ​​of the Type column that value is not) you want to generate in the form, instead of a drop-down list, a normal input type input, to add this new value to both the created team, and to the drop-down list (which is automatically added because it would be a new unique value in Tipo column)

Code HTML

```html
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select  formControlName="tipo"   placeholder="Tipo" >

        <mat-option *ngFor='let x of tipo_unique' [value]='x'>    
                            {{x}}
         </mat-option>
      </mat-select>   
     <mat-error>Este Campo es Requerido</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Coded where **Data** is my complete Json that I get to consume, and **tipo_unique** ends up being the only values ​​of my field Yipo

```js
unique1={}
tipo_unique=[];

this.PrtgService.getAllElements(this.table).subscribe(Data =>
            console.log(Data);
            this.tipo_unique=Data.forEach(item=>this.unique1[item.tipo]=1);
            console.log(this.tipo_unique)
            this.tipo_unique=Object.keys(this.unique1);
            console.log(this.tipo_unique);
```

Comment: must be `*ngFor="let x of tipo_unique"` (without "data") because your variable is called tipo_unique